# Insert error in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this function:

```
   public static function insert_user($user)
{
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("speakom",$con) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (user_ip,user_name,full_name,email_address,password,gender,birthday,banned,role,country) 
        VALUES('".$user->ip."','".$user->name."','".$user->full_name."','".$user->email."','".$user->password."',".$user->gender.",'".$user->birthday."',".$user->banned.",".$user->role.",'".$user->country."'") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

And I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

Where does the error point to ? how do I know  where the error is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the closing `)` from the `VALUES (` clause.  In general, it's easier to assign your SQL to a variable (which you can output for debugging purposes like this) prior to passing it to `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of yelling you should use PDO and prepared statements, here's the answer in PDO style:

```
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=speakom', 'root', ''); // optionally add encoding options
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // enable exception throwing
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user (user_ip, user_name, full_name, email_address, password, gender, birthday, banned, role, country) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array(
    $user->ip, $user->name, $user->full_name, $user->email, $user->password, 
    $user->gender, $user->birthday, $user->banned, $user->role, $user->country,
));
```

**Disclaimer** didn't test this, but it should give you a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

would you run

```
echo "INSERT INTO user (user_ip,user_name,full_name,email_address,password,gender,birthday,banned,role,country)      VALUES('".$user->ip."','".$user->name."','".$user->full_name."','".$user->email."','".$user->password."',".$user->gender.",'".$user->birthday."',".$user->banned.",".$user->role.",'".$user->country."'";
```

and i advise you to use `user` instead of `user`

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES('".$user->ip."','".$user->name."','".$user->full_name."','".$user->email."','".$user->password."',".$user->gender.",'".$user->birthday."',".$user->banned.",".$user->role.",'".$user->country."'"
```

You are missing `)` at the end. By the way, use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: what does it give me mysqli? are those prepared statements?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Yes, they are.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

Some of the values you want to insert are not in quote, and you missed the closing `)` for `VALUES`. Try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (user_ip,user_name,full_name,email_address,password,gender,birthday,banned,role,country) 
    VALUES('$user->ip', '$user->name','$user->full_name', '$user->email', '$user->password', '$user->gender', '$user->birthday', '$user->banned', '$user->role', '$user->country')") or die(mysql_error());
```